# Organising an Cloud Endpoint's class methods

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to abstract various endpoint methods in their own modules, and then import them into the main api file. So let's say this is the mail file:

```
@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(SomeMessage, SomeMessage, path='somepath', http_method='GET', name='someName')
    def getContent(self, request):
        # handle content
        return request
```

How can I abstract this endpoint method in its own module, and import it back to be used with the `MyApi` class?

Comment: You mean binding methods to an instance like so? https://ideone.com/KSwamw I'm trying to understand the question.

Comment: @Caramiriel, pardon my novice python knowledge. Basically I am hoping to put `getContents` method (among other related methods) in its own module, so as to not flood the MyApi class with all methods. The @endpoints decorators are from Google Cloud Endpoints; I am not certain how it would work.